# composer selfupdate Connection reset by peer

Tags: php, windows, ubuntu, composer-php, debian

I use ubuntu in windows, and when i run `composer selfupdate` composer send me an error

`[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: SSL: Connection reset by peer
  Failed to enable crypto
  failed to open stream: operation failed`

It's the same error in debian for windows.

But when i running `composer selfupdate` on powershell of windows

i don't have any error.

conf ubuntu

`php -v
PHP 7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans`

conf debian

`php -v
PHP 7.1.18-1+0~20180611145904.18+stretch~1.gbp2b32f6 (cli) (built: Jun 11 2018 14:59:07) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.18-1+0~20180611145904.18+stretch~1.gbp2b32f6, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies`

conf windows

Windows 10 pro
Version 1803
Version OS 17134.1

`php -v
PHP 7.0.23 (cli) (built: Aug 29 2017 06:13:57) ( ZTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to disable your antivirus, or try to whitelist that connection depending on which client you're using.
I already had this problem with Kaspersky.

Once disabled, the problem flew away.